# How do I make turn my existing menu into a responsive dropdown menu?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I currently have a menu that I'm building and items are positioned as they need to be, but I want some of the options to be hidden and shown below when the appropriate header is hovered over.

I've tried doing it with what I thought would make sense in CSS (display: none for the class that needs to be hidden) but I've not really got further than that. I have a burger menu icon hidden also.

```html
    <header>

        <div class="logo-container">
            <img src="img/bobCircle.svg" alt="your logo here" class="logo">
        </div>

        <nav class="menu">
            <ul class="menuitems">
                <li class="home"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li class="about"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Market <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a></li>
                    <li class="menu2"><a href="#">Buy X</a></li>
                    <li class="menu2"><a href="#">Sell X</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Market 2 <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a></li>
                    <li class="menu2"><a href="#">Buy X</a></li>
                    <li class="menu2"><a href="#">Sell X</a></li>
            </ul>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
        </nav>

        <div class="livesupport">
            <button>Contact live support</button>
        </div>

    </header>
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: #D7E1E9;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

button {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    margin: auto;
    background: #232323;
}

.logo-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 20px;
    flex: 1;
}

.logo {
    height: 80px;
}

.menu {
    display: flex;
    color: white;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex: 4;
}

.menuitems {
    display: flex;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.livesupport {
    display: flex;
    height: 50%;
    justify-content: center;
    flex: 1;
}

.menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.menu a:hover {
    color: #166BA5;
}

.menu .icon {
    display: none;
}

.menu2 {
    display:none;
}
```

I expect the hidden items to appear below the items with the arrows when the mouse has hovered over them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking into displaying items when their parent has been `:hover`ed. For example:

```css
.menuitems .dropdown .menu2 {
    display: none
}
.menuitems .dropdown:hover .menu2 {
    display: flex
}
```

Essentially toggle the appropriate field's display on/off when hovering over their parents.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp

Comment: Unfortunately that just took me back to everything being shown at once :(

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I needed to create another ul inside of my existing li element to stack them inside of each other.